# OpenJDK 11.0.8 Java causing CPU spike for Pentaho 9.4 spoon startup

Tags: java-11, pentaho-spoon

I have observed that the CPU usage spikes up to 60-70% during the startup of Pentaho 9.3 (Community Edition) spoon.bat. I am running pentaho using OpenJDK 11.0.8.

Thanks